# css hide first &nbsp; in div, but only first

Tags: javascript, html, css

Are there any good ways, to hide first `&nbsp;` in div, but only first?

For example I have this structure:

```
<div class="lalala">
 <div class="123">
    &nbsp; dfsdfsdf
     sdf sdf sd fsd f
      &nbsp; 
 </div>
 <div class="456">
   &nbsp; f dfgd
 </div>
</div>
```

As result I must see:

```
<div class="lalala">
     <div class="123">
        dfsdfsdf
         sdf sdf sd fsd f
```

Is it possible to do it in CSS only (and how?), or do I have to use JavaScript?

Comment: Is the `&nbsp;` (spaces) added because you want space before and after the text in `div.123`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a CSS way to do it.

With JavaScript it's fairly simple though:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.123');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '');
```

Comment: This does exactly what the OP wants. And nope, there's no CSS way to do it, indeed. +1

Comment: hm, but how to be if i have only class for first div, and then only div div

Comment: @PavelBY `var el = document.querySelector('.lalal').nextElementSibling;`

Comment: also, it seems that replaced will be all &nbsp; but how only first in div?

Comment: `replace` only replaces the first occurance. You need a global regexp to replace all (which i haven't used).

Comment: i'm new to js, could it have regex expression? like i need to select .123_somerandom ?